# How can I determine what is causing a newly creaking ceiling?

Tags: attic, noise

There's an area of my ceiling that has rather suddenly (in the last week) started creaking when the wind blows.

It's at a juncture with a wall, right below the attic, and it is very localized (at least it sounds like it is coming from a very specific spot, above some crown molding). I'm planning to go into the attic to look at it. What should I look for, and what else might it be?  (I don't think it's the actual crown molding -- I can't reproduce the sound by pressing on the crown molding. But this crown molding is slightly cracked from some years back, presumably from some movement in this area.)

Answer (score 2):

Trusses used for roof support?  Peak wind can cause truss movement.

Look where wall plates intersect trusses.  May be a nail sliding.  Use a mending plate or hurricane tie to reconnect.

[image]